# Rows And Columns dynamically to a Datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

First of all sorry about my english.
I'm trying to generate Datagrid with dynamic Columns and Rows. 
I found this way to add Columns:

```
DataGridTemplateColumn dgc = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
dgc.Header = templateField.CopyField.FieldName;
DataTemplate dtm = new DataTemplate();
FrameworkElementFactory frameElementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
dtm.VisualTree = frameElementFactory;
dgc.CellTemplate = dtm;
UC_CopyReferenceGrid.Columns.Add(dgc);
```

Where UC_CopyReferenceGrid is my DataGrid. 
But my problem is that I can't generate the rows, because I can't bind the columns and I don't know how I can add rows and edit cells.

Thank you very much.

Comment: WPF DataGrids are meant to be bound to a collection of objects, and will automatically generate a row for each item in the collection. Columns are either auto-generated too based on the properties of each item in the collection, or you can specify your own. For example, all you should need is `UC_CopyReferenceGrid.ItemsSource = SomeObservableCollection;`, where `SomeObservableCollection` is an `ObservableCollection<SomeObject>`. It will automatically render a row for each item in the collection and by default will create a column for each public property of `SomeObject`

Comment: So I should change the DataGrid? Because I don't have an object with all the properties, because it depends on some values in database.

Comment: If you're looking to use WPF the way it's meant to be used with it's binding system, then yes I would recommend you create an object to represent your database items, and bind your Grid to a collection of this object. I recommend `ObservableCollection<T>` because it will automatically notify any UI bindings to refresh whenever an item gets added or removed from the collection. If your columns truly are dynamic, I'd recommend checking out [Paul Stovell's article on how to deal with dynamic columns for a DataGrid](http://paulstovell.com/blog/dynamic-datagrid)

Comment: No, I don't want the binding system. I think I can't do what I want with a DataGrid.

Comment: I need something generic. I want to choose the information to insert in any cell, and this doesn't depend to a specific model. I try to do with a Grid generating rows and columns but y loose the copy/paste properties.